# synergy and ubuntu lock screen problem on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, lock-screen, synergy

I have a setup on work with a Ubuntu 12.04 and a Windows 7 PC which share same keyboard and same mouse via synergy. On Ubuntu the synergy server is running, on the Windows 7 the synergy client is running.

If I come back from my lunch break and the mouse focus is on my windows 7 screen. I see that for a fraction of a second the ubuntu screen isn't locked properbly i can see the whole Desktop. It is possible to type something in a bash terminal on the Ubuntu Screen. Then after that fraction of a second the screen is locked and a password is required. I think this is a security problem. How can i fix that? Is this a known problem on ubuntu 12.04?